# Ubuntu Settings Interface Changed

Tags: 16.10, settings, interface

After I upgraded to 16.10, My Settings interface changed a lot. Some programs are **same** functions but with different interfaces.

Why this happens and how can I deal with it?

Original Settings interface:

[image: Original Settings interface]

Current Settings interface:

[image: Current Settings interface]

Comment: You also installed Gnome desktop, didn't you?

Comment: I just upgraded my 16.04.1 to 16.10, then these happens...